# ImportError while running "Flask run app.py" but if I run "python3 app.py" then there is no import error and works fine

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

from transformers import pipeline
#import transformers
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model='facebook/bart-large-cnn' )#t5-large
print("summarizer loaded")

class Summary(Resource):
    def post(self):
        # write what to do for post request and Add class
        #Load the data
        postedData = request.get_json()

        #Validate the data

        news = postedData['news']
        summary_extractive = summarizer(news,min_length=90, max_length = 120)


        #make json and return
        retJSON = {
            'Message': summary_extractive[0]['summary_text'],
            'word_count': len(summary_extractive[0]['summary_text'].split()),
            'Status Code': 200,
        }

        return jsonify(retJSON)


api.add_resource(Summary, '/get_summary')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)#host='0.0.0.0'
```

Error while running with flask run:

> from transformers import pipeline
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'pipeline' from 'transformers' (unknown location)

But if I run with python3 app.py then there is no error.

I'm working in venv enviroment on macOS.
In `pip list` I'm able find the missing module `transformer`.

Comment: flask run worked for me in a fresh env these is my pip freeze :aniso8601==8.0.0
certifi==2020.4.5.2
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
future==0.18.2
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.15.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.5
packaging==20.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytz==2020.1
regex==2020.6.8
requests==2.23.0
sacremoses==0.0.43
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
tokenizers==0.7.0
torch==1.5.0
tqdm==4.46.1
transformers==2.11.0
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1

Comment: I have never worked with Flask, but you should check if `sys.path` is the same when you run your code with Flask and python3.

Comment: What does `which flask` say?

Comment: @expectedAn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/flask

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue which is causes due to old version of pip. Follow the below step to resolved the issue:

- upgrade your pip version use this command `pip install --upgrade pip`
- Uninstall old version of transformer `pip uninstall transformers`
- install again `pip install transformers`

**It works have a nice day**